# 2 formats in 1 crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I might be very stupid to ask this question. But I really hav no idea how to do it.
My boss wants to get a crystal report and he wants 2 formats.
that means he wants summary page on page 1 with one format and details page on page 2 with another format. 
So I have been thinking two ways. 
1st way is to get 2 formats in 1 crystal report. I hav never done that before and I couldn't find it online.
2nd way is to do 2 crystal reports and combine them. I hav no idea how to do that also.
So anybody can help?
may b both of my ways may b wrong.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi William,

Can you give us a few more details - for example, what sort of summary does he want on page one: just grand totals, or groups of subtotals?

Comment: Hi.. actually I thought of the solution to use subreports. and starts the subreport on a new page. hide the subreport's page number and border, it would look like the continuation of main report. just one problem, when i click on the subreport, it will appear on a new tab. if i can disable that, i m done. anyway to do that?
tkz btw..

Comment: I was originally going to suggest putting totals in the report header, if it could be used to meet your requirements, as being much simpler than inserting a subreport. However, now that you've gone to the effort of building the subreport...

Comment: As for disabling the drill down on the subreport - I don't know any way to do this, although I did turn up a couple of workarounds here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting_/Crystal_Reports/Q_21559923.html . These are (a) restrict the report to output to pdf in the pdf viewer, rather than in the report viewer, or (b) place an empty text control *over* the subreport, and set formulas for its layout to match those of the subreport (thus preventing the user from clicking on the subreport itself.)

Comment: That answer seems interesting..
We found an ugly workaround. We place an empty text control *over* the subreport, and set formulas for its layout to match those of the subreport. That essentially disables the drill-down because the user is unable to click on the subreport itself. It's ugly, but it works.
But I m not very clear about it.. could u explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I m the one who asks the questions. I know what to do now. and for the sakes of others (beginners like me), I share my experience.
Crystal reports doesn't allow you to have 2 formats in 1 reports.
Cyrstal reports doesn't allow you to export 2 different reports (not subreports) at the same time.
So.. I would do like this.
First, if I want to get 2 different reports, like Summary Page on 1st page and Details Page on 2nd, I will use subreport. But subreport will redirect u to that report itself when u click on it.
I dun want that either.
So I will cover subreport with text object with no background.
But I can't adjust the height of that text object.
I will use this
IEnumerator ie = mycrystalreport.Section1.ReportObjects.GetEnumerator();

```
        ie.Reset();

        while (ie.MoveNext())

            if (ie.Current != null && ie.Current.GetType().ToString().Equals("CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject"))

            {

                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject to = (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)ie.Current;

                if (to.Name == "my_text_object ")

                    to.Height = "the number you want. might need to calculate";



            }
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The ways I can think of (depending on the complexity of the summary requirements) are:

1. Include value totals in the report heading, with a page break at the start of the first report group.
2. Include a crosstab with the summary details in the report heading section.
3. Insert a subreport in the report heading section.